# How to execute Python3 script and get the print output in node-red?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, node-red

I have a node-red server and I want to create automatic processes to run my scripts in node-red, put the (print output) that is coming from the `client` script.

[image]

When I execute the same file through Pycharm, it works and I see the print on the console.

When I execute it through node-red via command line in `exec` such as:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/mac/Documents/local-node-red3/Client.py
```

It seems like it is working and sends sudo pass permission to node-red terminal. I give the permissions and initiate the other scripts. But at the end, nothing comes up to the node-red screen.

*Note:  I added the side bar to show you, somehow I was able to capture the exception thread in node-red for the error. If this is shown here why not the results in the console?*

If I go back to Pycharm and execute the client script there, prints start to show up in Pycharm as it is supposed to be. But again, nothing in the node-red side.

I have 5 different scripts in total, 4 of them is executed in Pycharm. I only want to execute the client here and get the output to node-red screen and visualise it in the chart afterwards.

Do I need to write additional function in `node-red` to read the print statement in order to read the `client` script output?

Comment: Try disabling python's output buffering

Comment: Thanks for the answer, If I understand correctly what you mean, I tried with both python -u and print('test', flush=True) does not work.

Comment: If i connect directly to the "text" node instead of "debug"node it works. Even though, the output is the same which is "msg.payload". I mean it is okay as long as i get it to my application. But isnt it strange? Is it a bug or am i missing something?

Comment: Go read about the difference between stdout and stderr